# Solving sparse linear system in Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have to solve the linear system A*x = b where A is a sparse matrix (34k x 34k). I tried to solve using x = b \ A but this gives me an out of memory error. Is there a better way to solve this system in Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong—you need to use:

```
x = A\b;
```

for the equation *Ax* = *b*

Comment: @MuhammadOmer No worries, it happens to everyone from time to time. :-)